# How To resolve Broken/Missing Handler with Independent views query backend flag links patch?

Tags: views, commerce, flags

So, I'm trying to do something that should be relatively simple, show a catalog of products based on a search index to provide a faceted search with some flag links.

I have a view based on a search index of product displays with a required relationship to 
Indexed Commerce Product: A bridge to node referenced by field_product_sku in order to pull the images into the view. My Flag is set to my custom product type (posters), and I can confirm it works.

The closest I've come was using patch #1[Independent backend query flag links](https://www.drupal.org/node/1362298) mentioned here. This works in so far as I now have access to Commerce Product: Flag Link for Entities, and Content: Flag Link for Entities, both of which give me a broken/missing handler message.

So: 1) How do I fix this? 2) is there a better way to get my Flag links into the Search view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling views cache. I believe it should remove broken/missing handler.

Comment: Very useful tip. I wasn't able to find that anywhere else, thanks